# In word, is there a reference from ribbon function to VBA?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, ribbon

I am maintaining a macro collection for myself with common tools I use in manual writing. When I need a function often, it's added.

Commonly I struggle to find which function in VBA matches the functions I use with the ribbon. In Word, some things can be recorded, others not. There doesn't seem to be logic in that recorder.

I am looking for some sort of reference table from "ribbon funcion" (the elements you can interact with on the ribbon) to VBA function / example. Does anyone know of such work, in books or elsewhere ?

Currently looking for ways to work with images and shapes, see arrows below. But same question applies for all functions.

I pretty much know my way around VBA, since 15+ years.

[image: Example ribbon (image settings) from Word, Danish version, with stock image selected]

Comment: The Ribbon, itself, is poorly represented in vba. The commands on the Ribbon, though are pretty much all there. Take a look at this page about modifying recorded macros. https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/ModifyRecordedMacro.htm You are really going to want to crack into the Word object model. Manipulation of shapes does not record well at all. Some links https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.shape https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Document.Shapes https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.inlineshapes Those may get you started.

Comment: Thanks, I do know how to manipulate recorded macros.  I was not after manipulating the ribbon - but some sort of reference going from button function (example: object position / text wrapping / color settings etc etc. ) - to VBA. This could actually be a  topic for an entire  book.   Microsoft documents VBA and object model well, but it's like VBA and the application are two different worlds in terms of documentation.